# ADT reverting back to standard Eclipse when installing plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I'm using the ADT of Eclipse, downloaded from the Android Dev site.  Each time I install a plugin and restart ADT, the splash screen reverts back from [this](http://lh4.ggpht.com/-GqCgKpPGDRg/ULgh19NsL7I/AAAAAAAAGO0/Mj5T8I2mDoA/adt-splash_thumb%25255B2%25255D.png?imgmax=800) (The ADT splash) to http://www.stuermer-benjamin.de/v12_1/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/001_launch_eclipse_4.2_juno.jpg&w=905&h=">this (The vanilla Eclipse splash).  After the application has loaded, the way I have my panels laid out reverts back to the default and the UI doesn't look like the regular Eclipse interface like [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/sites/default/files/Juno.png?1340832628) instead the elements are grey and boxy.  The plugin then never works - when I try to perform an action that the plugin should handle I get an error message popup.

I've had this happen with any plugin I try to use (from the Help > Install new software... dialog).  Each time I have had to delete and recreate my Eclipse program folder with a fresh download.  Does anyone know what is going wrong and how I can fix this/install plugins correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and it's reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126

**Edit:** It's solved: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126#c73

Comment: Glad to see this has been fixed!